# Fourier transform of an ellipse

Tags: fourier-transform

How to compute the Fourier transform of an ellipse (the interior), please?

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

$$F(u, v) = \mathcal{F} \left\{ f(x, y) \right\} = \int\int f(x, y) e^{2\pi i (ux + vy)}\, d x d y =\int \left[ \int f(x,y) e^{2\pi i ux}d x \right] e^{2\pi i v y }d y $$

I assume that I need an ellipse in the polar coordinate system, right?

For a circle, it is like this: Yes, I mean with its interior. For a circle it is like this: https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.coecis.cornell.edu/dist/c/442/files/2021/05/Fourier-Transforms-2D.pdf

Comment: The equation of an ellipse is not a function, it's a relation so it's unclear what $f(x,y)$ would be other than $1$.

Comment: Is $f$ the indicator function of your ellipse? If so you should indicate it clearly ...

Comment: The indicator function of $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ is $0$ almost everywhere, so its Fourier transform would be $0$.  Perhaps you mean the indicator function of the ellipse with its interior, $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 \le 1$?

Comment: Yes, I mean with its interior. For a circle it is like this: https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.coecis.cornell.edu/dist/c/442/files/2021/05/Fourier-Transforms-2D.pdf

Comment: There seems to be a claim in https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSA.57.001325 that an analytical formula exists. In https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.2.000852 the elliptical shape is approximated by a series of rectangles. Also relevant perhaps: https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSA.46.000285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\iint_{x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2\le 1} e^{2\pi i ux}e^{2\pi i vy} dxdy
$$
$$
=\int_{-b}^b dy e^{2\pi i vy} \int_{-a\sqrt{1-y^2/b^2}}^{a\sqrt{1-y^2/b^2}} e^{2\pi i ux}dx
$$
The substitution $x'=x/a$, $y'=y/b$, then renaming $y'\to y$, $x'\to x$ yields
$$
=ab\int_{-1}^1 dy e^{2\pi i vby} \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} e^{2\pi i uax}dx
$$
$$
= ab \frac{1}{2\pi i u a} \int_{-1}^1 dy e^{2\pi i vby} e^{2\pi i u a x}\mid _{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{2\pi i u} \int_{-1}^1 dy e^{2\pi i vby}
[e^{2\pi i u a \sqrt{1-y^2}}
-
e^{-2\pi i u a \sqrt{1-y^2}}
]
$$
The substitution $y=\sin\alpha$, $dy=\cos\alpha d\alpha$ yields
$$
= b \frac{1}{2\pi  iu} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\alpha e^{2\pi i vb\sin\alpha}
[e^{2\pi i u a \cos\alpha}
-
e^{-2\pi i u a \cos\alpha}
]\cos\alpha
$$
Euler's formuals for the complex exponential $(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/(2i)$ yield
$$
= b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\alpha e^{2\pi i vb\sin\alpha}
\sin(2\pi u a \cos\alpha)
\cos\alpha
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\alpha e^{2\pi i vb\sin\alpha}
\sin(2\pi u a \cos\alpha)
\cos\alpha
+b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2}^0 d\alpha e^{2\pi i vb\sin\alpha}
\sin(2\pi u a \cos\alpha)
\cos\alpha
$$
The substitution $\alpha =-\tau$ in the second of these integrals, $\cos(-\tau)=\cos(\tau)$ and
$\sin(-\tau)=-\sin\tau$ plus Euler's formula for $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$ yields
$$
= 2b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\alpha \cos(2\pi vb\sin\alpha)
\sin(2\pi u a \cos\alpha)
\cos\alpha
$$

$$
= 2b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi u a \cos\alpha)
\cos(2\pi vb\sin\alpha)
\cos\alpha
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi (ua\cos\alpha -vb\sin\alpha) )
+\sin(2\pi (ua\cos\alpha+vb\sin\alpha) )
]
\cos\alpha
$$
Define the unitless amplitude $c\equiv \sqrt{(ua)^2+(vb)^2}$,
$\cos \beta=ua/c$, $\sin\beta=vb/c$,
$$
= b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi c (\cos\alpha \cos\beta -\sin\alpha\sin\beta) )
+\sin(2\pi c (\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta) )
]
\cos\alpha
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha +\beta))
+\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha-\beta))
]
\cos\alpha
$$
$$
= -b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_0^{-\pi/2} d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi c \cos(-\alpha +\beta))
+\sin(2\pi c \cos(-\alpha-\beta))
]
\cos(-\alpha)
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2}^0 d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha +\beta))
+\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha-\beta))
]
\cos(\alpha)
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{2\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha +\beta))
+\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha-\beta))
]
\cos(\alpha)
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{2\pi  u} \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha -\pi +\beta))
+\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha-\pi -\beta))
]
\cos(\alpha-\pi)
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{2\pi  u} \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} d\alpha
[-\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha +\beta))
-\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha -\beta))
]
(-)\cos(\alpha)
$$
$$
= b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} d\alpha
[\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha +\beta))
+\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha -\beta))
]
\cos(\alpha)
$$

$$
= b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha +\beta))
\cos\alpha
+ b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos(\alpha-\beta))
\cos\alpha
$$

$$
= b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2+\beta}^{3\pi/2+\beta} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\cos(\alpha-\beta)
+ b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2-\beta}^{3\pi/2-\beta} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\cos(\alpha+\beta)
$$

$$
=
b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2+\beta}^{3\pi/2+\beta} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\cos \alpha \cos\beta
+b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \int_{-\pi/2+\beta}^{3\pi/2+\beta} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\sin \alpha \sin\beta
+ (\beta \leftrightarrow -\beta)
$$

$$
=
b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \cos\beta \int_0^{2\pi} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\cos \alpha
+b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \sin\beta \int_0^{2\pi} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\sin \alpha
+ (\beta \leftrightarrow -\beta)
$$

$$
=
b \frac{1}{4\pi  u} \cos\beta \int_0^{2\pi} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\cos \alpha
+ (\beta \leftrightarrow -\beta)
$$
$$
=
b \frac{1}{2\pi  u} \cos\beta \int_0^{\pi} d\alpha
\sin(2\pi c \cos \alpha )
\cos \alpha
+ (\beta \leftrightarrow -\beta)
$$

$$
=
b \frac{1}{2  u} \cos\beta J_1(2\pi c)
+ (\beta \leftrightarrow -\beta)
$$
$$
=
b \frac{1}{u} \cos\beta J_1(2\pi c)
=
\frac{ab}{c} J_1(2\pi c)
$$

Comment: Thank you. How exponential become cos between the 7th and 8th row, please?

Comment: This is adding the contribution from the $\alpha<0$ and $\alpha>0$ where $\cos(-\alpha)=\cos\alpha$ does not change in 2 of the factors, and Euler's formula for $e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x$ can be used to cover the change in the exponent.

Comment: Thank you and the sum, please? How to arrive to it?

Comment: The sum is the standard Taylor series approximation for $\sin x=x-x^3/6+x^5/120...$. The convergence is only good if $2\pi ua$ is small. Otherwise one should better use the Taylor series of the cosine factor.

Comment: Thank you and why there is k! in the denominater instead of (2k+1)! (it is in Taylor series for sin)?

Comment: Why the sum is not over k from 0 to infinity, please?

Comment: I'll correct the k! error in the series expansion...

Comment: The sum $k\ge 0$ *is* from 0 to infinity. This is standard notation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.